# ajax calls being called too fast

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, facebook

I have a page with a link, that the user clicks to log our api out of Facebook.  When you click on it, it calls a ajax function that calls a php method to delete the users keys from our database, then calls the Facebook api logout function from a JS command. This calls Facebook and ends the users session. Once logged out, it refreshes the page.

My issue is that it seems to be not waiting for the database update to finish and logouts of Facebook and refreshes the page.  Since it doesn't finish it, the info is never deleted and my site never logs out.  Every once in a while, it does wok, but maybe once every 10 clicks.

I put in a setTimeout for 2 secs, but it still didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you waiting for the AJAX callback? Since it's an asynchronous request, you aren't guaranteed that it's finished until it calls the `onreadystatechange()` function with `status=4`.

**EDIT:** An example of what I'm talking about:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.responseText == 'logged out successfully') {
    facebookLogout(uid);
  }
}
xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/my_logout.php?uid=' + uid, true);
xhr.send();
```

**EDIT 2:** To clarify your questions in the comments:

1) Yeah, PHP would just has to do an echo. It's not necessary - I just added that as an example to make sure the request finished not because it failed/got aborted.

2) As for `$.get` and friends, that's jQuery rather than pure Javascript, which has its own tools. In jQuery you'd write something like:

```
$.get('my_logout.php?uid=' + uid, function(data) {
   if (data == 'logged out successfully') {
     facebookLogout(uid);
   }
 });
```

Comment: How is this request used?  can this be done with a $.get call?  And the php function just returns something with and echo, correct?

Comment: that is in the $(document).ready(function(){ function.  I'm new to the whole JS realm and trying to make sure I understand it all

Comment: @Nathan: which library?  It looks like jquery maybe?  jQuery `get` takes a callback function, that is where you should put your follow-up code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `setTimeout` to try to time a follow-up action to an Ajax call.  Use a callback function instead; that way it is guaranteed to only execute after the Ajax call is finished.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments, I see that you're using jQuery. In this case you just need to pass-in a callback function as function argument. Also see the [jQuery.get documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

```
$.get('foo.php', function() {
    alert('Finished!');
});
```

or

```
$.get('foo.php', functionname);

// ...

function functionname() {
    alert('Finished!');
}
```

To learn more about jQuery I strongly recommend to learn how to find/read/interpret their online documentation. It's really excellent. There's also a [Tutorials section](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) at the home page. jQuery is not *just* JavaScript. It's a JavaScript based library.

Comment: I tried this method but it seems to just sit there and never picks up on the echo return.

Comment: I found post, and thought it would work, so I used this command
$.post(domain,{subject:'Hi'}, function(data){

and when I run the method directly through the url, I get this output that is echoed then killed from the php methods.
{"status":1}

for some reason the post is crashing and its never executes the logout call.  Any ideas?

I have an alert before and after, and they both run.